# Do I need to add routes with the OPTIONS method to OpenAPI?

Tags: rest, openapi

As the [documentation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS):

> The HTTP `OPTIONS` method requests permitted communication options for a given URL or server.

From this we can conclude that the server must have an HTTP route with the `OPTIONS` method for absolutely all URLs.

For example, if the server has the following route list:

```
GET /
GET /users
GET /posts
```

In this case, the server must also have the following routes:

```
OPTIONS /
OPTIONS /users
OPTIONS /posts
```

1. Am I correct in my understanding that absolutely all routes must have an `OPTIONS` method?
2. Should the OpenAPI documentation show all routes with `OPTIONS` methods?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Am I correct in my understanding that absolutely all routes must have an OPTIONS method?

Not necessarily. As demonstrated by the examples in the documentation you've shared, there are two main use-cases for an OPTIONS request:

- To inform your API's user of the allowed HTTP methods (e.g. GET, POST, PATCH, etc.) for the requested path.
- To service pre-flight requests that are sent as part of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). For example, if a common browser (such as Firefox or Chrome) visits a URL which redirects to a path of your API, the browser's CORS checks may mark the request to your API as [pre-flighted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests), in which case an OPTIONS request will be sent before the originally intended request.

If you don't intend to inform your user of the allowed methods for a path and  if you are not planning for your API to support pre-flighted requests, then you don't need to define routes for the OPTIONS method.

> 2. Should the OpenAPI documentation show all routes with OPTIONS methods?

Yes. If your HTTP server services OPTIONS requests for certain paths, then this should be indicated in your OpenAPI specification so that the specification is a more complete description of your API implementation.